# How to break insert query, before insert trigger mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to avoid insert query if some condition get false in Before Insert trigger mysql ?

**Here is an example what i want to do:**

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mtdb`.`Mytable_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `Mytable` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.mobile IS NULL OR NEW.mobile = "")
        THEN
            **DO NOT INSERT, RETURN SOME ERROR MESSAGE
        END IF;
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of

1. Use "[Signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)" to stop the execution.
2. Change the value of your data such that it violates some constraints, such as setting the primary key to NULL.